# How to center Google sign in Button in a Svelte App

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-signin, svelte

I'm trying to center the Google sign in button in my svelte app, but this doesn't work. Same thing also happen using a Svelte Atoms component [FileUpload](https://svelte-atoms.web.app/FileUpload). If I use a standard button, this will be centered in the app. Does anyone has an idea how I can solve that problem? My code is based on the svelte template, here the specific part:

```
<main>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-longtitle="true" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    <button>Gte an random number</button>
    <FileUpload title="Upload file" subtitle={fileName} on:change={onChange} />
    <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
</main>

<style>
    main {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1em;
        max-width: 240px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
```

[image: Here is how it looks like and I want that both components will be centered]

Thanks
Paulo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question of CSS, there are several ways to center your component.

```css
main {
  ...
  display: flex; /* or grid */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```